# PHP - Updating MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to update a MySQL database with PHP.

Here is my code:

```
$tableName = "Licenses";
$searchVariable = "used";
$selectVariable = "verCode";
$verTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$userUUID = "test_string";
$verID = "79A4D";

mysql_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_pass") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("licenses_db") or die(mysql_error());
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `{$tableName}` WHERE `{$searchVariable}`='{$verID}'") or die(mysql_error());

while($info = mysql_fetch_array($data)) {
    //Verification ID unused, so verify the user
    foreach($info as $key => $value) {
        echo "$key: $value</br>";
        }
    if ($info['used'] == 0) {
        echo "<br/>UPDATE `{$tableName}` SET '{$selectVariable}'=1,'time'=`{$verTime}`,'UUID'=`{$userUUID}`; WHERE `{$searchVariable}`='{$verID}'<br/>";
            // the above is to see what command is used
        mysql_query("UPDATE `{$tableName}` SET '{$selectVariable}'=1,'time'=`{$verTime}`,'UUID'=`{$userUUID}`; WHERE `{$searchVariable}`='{$verID}'");
        echo "data updated";
        return 'Success';
        }
    //Verification ID was used already
    else {
        echo "found but used";
        return 'Error Message';
        }
    }
echo "not found";
return 'Error Message';
```

However, the database doesn't update. I have the table `Licenses` created in `license_db`. In addition, I have one row with the following values:

```
verCode = 79A4D
used = 0
UUID = NULL
time = NULL
```

If I run the program the first time, it should update the database. This is printed out:

```
0: 79A4D
verCode: 79A4D
1: 
used: 
2: 
UUID: 
3: 
time: 

UPDATE `Licenses` SET 'used'=1,'time'=`2014-02-15 19:14:13`,'UUID'=`test_string`; WHERE `verCode`='79A4D'
data updated
```

When I run it the second time, `used` is now 1, and so it should print out `found but used`. However, the `data updated` section (with the `UPDATE ...`) is printed out.

So, the database is not updating. How can I solve this? Thanks!

Comment: The [mysql functions are deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944956/the-mysql-extension-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-the-future-use-mysqli) and therefore not a great place to start learning how to access a MySQL database from PHP.

Comment: You noticed you entered a `;` delimiter ? try removing it any see what is gonna happen..

Comment: @OrelEraki Same result.

Comment: @F3AR3DLEGEND, Can you put `or die(mysql_error());` after every `mysql_query` you got, and run so we could see the errors ?

Comment: You should use backtick for table name and columns and quotes for values, you inverted them in last query

Comment: @Fabio Yeah that fixed the issue. However, it still updates every time. I don't think I'm getting the value correctly for the column `used`. Using phpAdmin on cPanel, I can see that `used` is set to 1, but the `if ($info['used'] == 0)` conditional is still executed.

Comment: @Fabio Sort of. It's a bit, because it's only supposed to be a Boolean value.

Comment: If it's not an integer try to surround with quotes == '0'

Comment: Where does this " \`{}\` " stuff come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

e.g.

```
"
UPDATE `$tableName`  
   SET `$selectVariable` = 1
     , `time` = '$verTime'
     , `UUID` = '$userUUID'
 WHERE `$searchVariable` = '$verID';
";
```

Comment: I had another issue. `$info['user']` == 0 is always True, even once the user = 1 (I checked the database using phpAdmin). If I try `== '0'`, it's always False...